# Regexp flag values with the 'R' letter or with preceding number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
LOCKR
-----
9R
R
Y
9R, 4O
```

And I would like to have this output:

```
OUTPUT
------
X
X
null
null
```

The logic is: if the column has either just R or a number before it (i.e. R, 2R, 3R...), then put an 'X' else null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match on the regex pattern `^\d*R$`:

```sql
SELECT LOCKR,
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(LOCKR, '^\d*R$') THEN 'X' END AS OUTPUT
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Comment: @astentx My answer completely stands on it own even without the image (as it so happens, my corporate proxy blocks the image).  I only include for convenience, and as an extra.